# Qt Creator doesn't load my custom widget plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

My OS is Win7 and I've installed Qt 5.5.0

I create a simple custom widget plugin
New Project->Other Project -> Qt Custom Designer Widget

after creating the dll , I copy it in
D:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer
and
D:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\designer

but in **Qt Creator** designer does not appear my widget in the widget box

but if I run **designer**.exe, **all ok** , my widget is displayed

i read [Qt Designer doesn't load my custom widget plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286883/qt-designer-doesnt-load-my-custom-widget-plugin)
and i read [How to promote a custom widget in QT Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684189/how-to-promote-a-custom-widget-in-qt-creator)

I came to the conclusion that qt creator does not work correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to comment. There are many possible reasons, why your plugin does not load. You can look for further information by opening a *.ui file in qt creator and then take a look in the menu: Tools->Form Editor->About QtDesigner Plugins.

If your plugin is listed there, you copied it in the right folder and you will get a hint why it does not load. In my experience, the most common mistake is, that your qt-creator was not build with mingw, but you are trying to load a plugin built with mingw. You need to use the same compiler for both.